# How to achieve Closure inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I read this on SO

> Closures are a difficult concept to come to grips with on the first try

Surely they are trickiest! So, I was working on one of the JavaScript closures exercise

```
//What changes required to for loop so that triggering loop1 will give output as 1
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
  $(document).on('loop'+i, function(){
     console.log(i);
  })
$(document).trigger('loop1');
```

Above will output `10`. Here basically, I am triggering event `loop1` and I want the output to be `1`. Changes I tried on top of above is

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
  $(document).on('loop'+i, (function(){
      return function(){console.log(i)}
  })());
$(document).trigger('loop1');
```

But that didn't helped either. It is still giving me `10`. What should i do to achieve the required output?

Comment: Just to make it clear, you don't have a closure inside the loop, you have an event handler

Comment: @adeneo Oh!..Ok..I Understand, So is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: Sure, you just add a closure -> **http://jsfiddle.net/swh3knfh/**